# Unable to connect to SQL Server through vnet from web app getting error

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-appservice

I'm new to vnet integration. I was created the Vnet1 in virtual network and subnet as subnet1 for web app and subnet2 for SQL Server. I create the Private endpoint connections with vnet1/subnet2 in SQL Server. I added Virtual network integration for webapp with vnet1/subnet1.

When running the web app, I get this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.)

I'm unable to get why this error is coming at the beginning it worked fine now we are facing this error. And many of the webapps are connecting to same vnet1/subnet1.

I'm stuck with this. What have I missed when connecting to SQL Server through private access from web app?

Comment: Vnet1 in virtual network and subnet as subnet1 for web app > You need to add this Vnet and subnet in the selected network settings of Azure SQL networking section

Comment: Refer this SO answer- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62276437/vnet-integration-for-azure-web-app-and-azure-sql-server

Comment: @SiddheshDesai, thank you for quick reply. thank you i haven't added in virtual network rule for those subnets . While adding new virtual network rule there is showing **service endpoints not enabled** means ? After adding this virtual network rule still facing same error

Comment: You need to enable service endpoint too for the microsoft.sql and add the web app subnet in the selected network of Azure SQL

Comment: @SiddheshDesai Enabled for vnet1/subnet1 (web app vnet) but still same error. restarted the app service also.

Comment: Did you add Microsoft.sql endpoint

Comment: yes i did it and restarted the web app

Comment: Have you checked Allow Azure Services in the Azure SQL networking section?

Comment: yes, it is not checked

Comment: Check it, And then try again, It will allow your Azure Web app to connect to Azure SQL allowing the Azure Web App Ip's in Azure SQL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256239/discussion-between-siddheshdesai-and-prasanthi).

Answer (score 1):

I created one Vnet and added 2 Subnets to it, I assigned one Subnet to my Azure SQL and Networking and One to my Azure Web App Integration, I also Selected Allow Azure Services in my Azure SQL Server Networking like below:-

***My Vnet- siliconVNET
2 Subnets -  1) default  2) siliconVnet:-***

[image]

**`default subnet:-`**

[image]

**`siliconVnet subnet:-`**

[image]

**My Azure SQL Server Networking:-**

[image]

**My Azure Web App VNET Integration:-**

[image]

[image]

***Azure Web App Loads successfully ans retrieves all the Data from Azure SQL:-***

[image]

Comment: Thank you for detail explanation.  It helped me and i just want to know where you have used default subnet ?

Comment: Default subnet is used for my Azure SQL